# How we can get the Mandatory sign in the Visual Force of SFDC?

Tags: salesforce

I am new to the `Visual Force` code of the `SDFC`. I wanted to get the Mandatory details need sign shown below on my developed code of "Entry Section" of pageBLockSection. How Can I do that ?

[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Block One">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Entry Section">
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.phone}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.billingcity}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!account.Industry}"/>

                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a input tag required, set required = 'true' for the input.

Ex, `<apex:inputtext value="{!Name}"  required="true"/>`

Comment: I mean ! = Required Information should  - This information I want to display  on page Block

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Just set `mode="edit"` on the pageBlock tag.